# Is it storage efficient the way github pull request works?

Tags: git, web-services, github, cloud-storage

In Github When I want to make edit on repository that I don't own, I fork  it which means I copy all the repository files/folders to my own storage space, then add edits in a branch ,at the end I make pull request in the original repository for the owner to merge

If every edit will make such copying of the whole repositories this will be huge waste of storage and exponential growth of redundant data.

**is this right, or I miss a big picture?**

Consider if it was not just text files , if is media files for every one to contribute with git

Comment: Somewhat related blog from the Github infrastructure team about their storage backend: http://githubengineering.com/introducing-dgit/

Comment: thanks from the article -> DGit uses this property of Git to keep three copies of every repository, on three different servers it now scaling more,

Comment: Well, the article does not say if a fork of the repo is placed on the same three servers (so that no actual copying needs to take place).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the internals of a closed-source repository hosting site.

Comment: I think Every one should Understand the philosophy , the implementation is private ,example everyone know philosophy of operating systems windows implementation is private for Microsoft

Comment: Is this a theoretical question because you're curious?  Or are you planning to make millions of forks of a repo?  :)

Comment: I am curious , knowledge is inspiring for everyone , Github must have protection to stop such attack of making milions of forks

Comment: I don't think that this is off-topic at all.  The FAQ says that "software tools commonly used by programmers" is on-topic, it doesn't say that those tools need to be open source.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, if a fork were a complete copy of the repository, then that would be very inefficient.  [GitHub's engineering blog](http://githubengineering.com/counting-objects/) points this out in a blog post about speeding up network operations:

> ...if each [fork] were its own copy of the repository, that would imply an incredible amount of redundant disk space, requiring several times more fileservers than the ones we have in our infrastructure.

Instead, GitHub forks make use of [git alternate storage](http://dustin.sallings.org/2008/12/30/git-alternates.html), which allows a repository to point its [repository object storage](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout) to another location.

This allows all the forks to point to a single on-disk location, which minimizes duplication and allows for optimizations across the forks.  The [blog post](http://githubengineering.com/counting-objects/) continues:

> That’s why we decided to use a feature of Git called alternates. When you fork a repository on GitHub, we create a shallow copy of it. This copy has no objects of its own, but it has access to all the objects of an alternate, a root repository we call network.git and which contains the objects for all the forks in the network. When you push to your repository, eventually we move over the objects you pushed to the network.git root, so they’re already available in case you decide to create a Pull Request against the original repository.
>
> With all the repositories in the network sharing the same pool of objects, we can keep all the objects inside of a single packfile, and hence minimize the on-disk size of the repository network by not storing all the duplicated objects between the forks.